# How to get reputation to post on the meta?

Tags: discussion, new-users, reputation

I'm sorry for posting here instead of on the meta but I'm not allowed to post on the meta. I need 5 reputation here to post in the sandbox. How am I supposed to get that if I am supposed to post in the sandbox before I post here?

Comment: Try your hand at any challenge. A single upvote is all it takes.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help

Comment: You shouldn't need 5 reputation. We've reduced the limit to 1, precisely for this reason, as is shown on our [help page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: That's odd. I do need 5 reputation. See here: https://imgur.com/gallery/IWOzN6n

Comment: I guess Stack Exchange is using magic numbers...